# Arvixe mail settings

Tags: web-hosting, webmail

I have a fast question.
I need to fill the below information in my web.config file
what do you think the correct information would be for an arvixe server with madares.com domain:

```
<add key="SmtpMailFrom" value="info@madares.com"/>
<add key="SmtpServer" value="Mail@madares.com"/>
<add key="SmtpUserName" value="info@madares.com"/>
<add key="emailpassword" value="×××××" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SMTP Server is mail.madares.com . The rest of the information looks correct if the e-mail account has been created on the server.